# Handle very large files with good performance

Tags: java, database, file-io, large-files

If I have 1 million lines in a file I cannot jump directly to 50000th line without iterating line by line (which is sequential access). This is my understanding after doing some research in Google.

If this is the case how about Database having 1TB of data where in it searches a row in few seconds. At the end of the day DB also stored in some formatted file with its own metadata.

Can it be possible to implement such a fast string search in a file of 1 million lines of records. What kind of implementation helps us to handle such a large scale of data...

Note Length of Each line may vary from 10 to 100.

Is it possible in Java?

Comment: *"If I have 1 million lines in a file I cannot jump directly to 50000th line without iterating line by line"*  Is the information sorted?  Does each line give that information as a key in the line?  If so, more efficient algorithms can be used to find the line using the sorted key.

Comment: *"Can it be possible to implement such a fast string search in a file of 1 million lines of records."*  I doubt it.  DBs typically use clever algorithms *combined with* data structures that are optimized for access in a 'non-linear' way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot jump directly to 50000th line without iterating line by line

Take a look at [random access file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Comment: The problem is knowing where to randomly access.

Comment: Are you sure that this is OP problem ? I'm not. I suspect that all his lines are the same size

Comment: Ok, how do you just to the `jump directly to 50000th line` with RandomAccessFile ?

Comment: What is the problem with it if all lines are the same size ?

Comment: That is a big assumption, but that would work if the maximum line length is not too large.

Comment: Even if you are going to index you file, this is trivial solution with few lines of code. And then you can use random access file. No need to use 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @Peter  New edit *"Note Length of Each line may vary from 10 to 100."*

Comment: @Anton Line size is not same it varies from 10 to 100. How can I know how much to skip? Or what would be the position of 50000th line to seek.

Comment: If you want to save on memory, you can store the position of the start of every 100 lines. You skip as far as you can, then iterate the rest of the way.  If you need to general indexing, use a tool like Lucene to build an index.

Comment: Lucene is overkill for such a simple task, index with line numbers can be stored in simple Map. Btw no clue why OP accepted my answer =)

Answer (score 8):

You need to maintain an index of where the lines are.  I have a library which does this [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle). Once the lines are indexed (which it builds do as you write them) you can access them randomly in as little as 100 ns.

It is designed to handle TB of data in the same file, or a relatively small number of files. If you have many thousands of files, you would need to use a different approach as the per file overhead would become significant.

Answer (score 2):

1- Read all lines only one time
 
2- put lineNumber(as Key) and startingPostionOfLine to a Map object.

Then,
you can get startingPostionOfLine= map.get(lineNumber).
 
After found startingPosition, jump with RandomAccessFile.seek(startingPosition)  method.

Comment: For the record, this suggestion is quite wasteful: all that is needed is an array of `long`s. That is likely two orders of magnitude more memory-efficient than a HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

You can adapt your file structure for binary search. Begin each line with a unique marker (a byte sequence not used in the line itself) followed by the line number. Searching for a line,

1. jump to a random location;
2. read forward until the marker;
3. read the line number;
4. if it's the one you're looking for, you're done; otherwise choose another random position to jump to (either greater or lower than the current position, based on the line number you found).

The more you can assume about your lines, the less random the jumps. For example, you can estimate location from average line length. You can also have a cache of some line locations to improve guessing.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the length of each line then you can use [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and then [skipBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#skipBytes%28int%29) to the line you want.